# Plotting 3 columns of rasters and saving into pdf with base R

Tags: r, pdf, plot, layout, raster

Sorry this example is not entirely reproducible (I do not provide exact input data), but hopefully the example will be clear.

In short, I would like to save three maps in a wide pdf format, so All three maps can be shown with a desired extent + there is an overarching title above (but I don't want it to take up half of the page).

I am really struggling with setting it up properly:

```
pdf("plots1.pdf",width = 30/2.54,height = 20/2.54)
par(mfrow = c(2,3))
layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,4), 2, 3, byrow = TRUE))
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,"Africa, Params_1",cex=2,font=2)
# plot.new()
# plot.new()
plot(r2_list[[1]], xlim = Region[[g]][1:2], ylim = Region[[g]][3:4],
     breaks=cuts, col = plasma(21), main = variable[1],legend=FALSE)
plot(wrld_simpl,add=TRUE)
plot(r2_list[[2]], xlim = Region[[g]][1:2], ylim = Region[[g]][3:4],
     breaks=cuts, col = plasma(21), main = variable[2],legend=FALSE)
lines(wrld_simpl)
plot(r2_list[[3]], xlim = Region[[g]][1:2], ylim = Region[[g]][3:4],
     breaks=cuts, col = plasma(21), main = variable[3])
lines(wrld_simpl)

dev.off()
```

I would also like to try to print 6 plots, again - with overarching titles but I fail miserably.
Help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `heights=` to your `layout` call.

```r
layout(matrix(c(1,1,1, 2,3,4), byrow=TRUE, nr=2), heights = c(1, 8))
opar <- par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,"Africa, Params_1",cex=2,font=2)
par(opar)
plot(1:20)
plot(3:99)
plot(1:2)
```

(Blue boundaries below added externally, for reference only.)

### Without `heights`

If I remove the `heights=` from the code above, I see this:

[image: plot 1, no heights]

### With `heights`

[image: plot 2, with heights]

(You will want to play with the actual values based on your canvas size, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! And how to strike a balance between canvas size and margins?
I do get an error: `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`
Not sure how to tackle it

Comment: That's the balance, and since I don't have access or knowledge of your specific layout, you will need to play with various ratios, font sizes, margins, etc. Notice how I added `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))` before the `text` and reset it afterwards? That is one technique to work around the "margins too large" thing. So perhaps try `heights=c(1,4)` and work up from there. (And it will behave differently within your `pdf()...dev.off()` canvas than in your interactive console. Joy.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is such a pain in base R, but will follow your advice. Alternatively I will try to set it up in ggplot2.

Comment: (That is likely a better option, though even with faster graphics in `ggplot2-3.3` and perhaps R-4's improved `grid` stuff ... it's still quite a bit slower than base graphics.)

Comment: MIH, while I think that `ggplot2::facet_*` will do what you need, but does this answer address your question on base graphics?

Comment: It does, thanks - I marked it as answered a moment ago.